# PHP: how to create a search form that will link to my search script

Tags: php, forms, search

I have a PHP search script which I've altered slightly and works well for me. But there is one part Im not sure how to do, and that is linking the script up to a search form, that a user can complete.

The script is below, and it searches a text file for key words. Currently the "key word" is entered directly into the script. But that is no good for someone visiting my site - so I wanted to create a search form. But not sure if I should use POST or GET or something else. And I dont know how I should link the code up from the form, to the script below. I've searched for quite a bit of time to find this, but cant see anything that covers it, and my attempts at getting it to link up arent going well. If anyone could help it would be most appreciated.

(original code borrowed from Lekensteyn - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3686246/1322744 (thanks))

```
<?php
$file = 'users.txt';
$searchfor = 'entersearchterm';

$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Found matches:<br />";
   echo implode("<br />", $matches[0]);
}
else{
   echo "No matches found";
fclose ($file); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code (a rough idea) :**

```
<html>
      <head><title>Search Form</title></head>
      <body>
            <form action="search.php" method="GET">
                   <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword width="50" value="" />
                   <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
            </form>
      </body>
</html>
```

**And get the keyword from your PHP script like this :**

```
<?php
// script.php


$searchfor = $_GET['keyword'];

$file = 'users.txt';

$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Found matches:<br />";
   echo implode("<br />", $matches[0]);
}
else{
   echo "No matches found";
fclose ($file); 
}
?>
```

Comment: @KGreen If you find that an answer is satisfactory enough, please do mark it as an "Answer" so that other people reading the same question in the community may benefit from it. :-)

Comment: erm. I dont know how to do this. I can only see where I can mark if it is helpful or not. Is there something else that I can do?

Comment: @KGreen Well, there is a "tick" below the "UP/DOWN" voting next to each answer. :-)

Comment: oh, so there is. now it's green :)

Comment: @KGreen Haha. Welcome to the amazing community of StackOverflow! :-)