# Calling lines from a text file and displaying a specific line

Tags: javascript, php, file, text

Sorry, I may not have worded that properly...

For this example, the text file will be called **example.txt**.
Also, the value will hereby be named "Apple"

What I am trying to do is take example.txt, open it, then find Apple and display the entire line that value rests on.

---

example.txt

---

The fastest land animal is a Cheetah.

The name of a small table is a Desk.

The name of a red fruit is Apple.

The maker of my car is Toyota.

My favorite gun is a Shotgun.

---

Webpage

---

[Line Displays Here]

---

I've tried MANY solutions to this (google is not my friend in this case. How dare you google!)
I'll post some of them to show you what I have tried. Keep in mind, I am still a bit new to php. I believe the farthest I got was opening the files and displaying an array....

```
    $file_handle = fopen("dictionary.txt", "rb");

    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    $parts = explode('=', $line_of_text);

    print $parts[0] . $parts[1]. "<BR>";

    }

    fclose($file_handle);
```

This did not work...

Nor did this

```
$lines = file('file.txt');

$output = '';
$TorZ = "Array
(";
$num = 0;
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    $output .= $TorZ.' '.$line.PHP_EOL;
    $TorZ = '['.$num.'] =>';
    $num++;
}

file_put_contents('output.txt', $output);
```

Or this..

```
$result = array();
$file = explode("\n", file_get_contents("file.txt"));
foreach ( $file as $content ) {
    $result[] = array_filter(array_map("trim", explode("\n", $content)));
}
var_dump($result);
```

Any ideas?

Also, I sincerely apologize if this has been answered in the past, I spent about 2 hours searching for a way to do this, and still cannot find anything.

Comment: Java is not Javascript

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I was looking for after spending a little more time searching and came up with this result. Works just like I wanted it to!
[PHP to search within txt file and echo the whole line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686177/php-to-search-within-txt-file-and-echo-the-whole-line)