# PHP : Find from tab delimited text file without while loop

Tags: php

I have one tab delimited text file (TXT) with more than **1 million** lines(records) and around **400 MB** file size

Example

```
demo    123333    new
demo2    3444442    new
demo4    56666632    old
demo5    455552333   new
```

So now I want to find out line which **2nd tab** is equal to **"56666632"**

also convert all tab value of that line covert into array like :

```
data[0]=>demo4
data[1]=>56666632
data[2]=>old
```

**Note :** I want without while and foreach because very large number of line in txt file

**I am try this code with while loop:**

```
$file = "feed.txt";
$cols = array();
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
$fh = fopen($file, 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($fh, 1000, "\t")) !== false) 
{ 
  if($line[1]=="56666632")
  {  
  var_dump($line);
  break;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're explicitly precluding the options that allow you to read the file line by line in PHP, then you're probably limited to OS search commands like grep.... but why don't you want to use loops?

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/3686287/2045041

Comment: `I want without while and foreach because very large number of line in txt file`. This seems wrong to me, you want to do that in line-per-line when you have big files otherwise you'll fall into memory issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a Linux box, you could try delegating the job to grep:

```
$line = shell_exec('grep -P "\t56666632\t" feed.txt');
```

Comment: ... and not really php based solution.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski shell_exec command use in PHP ...so this is php based solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have a hard time doing this without a `foreach` or `while` loop. So hard, in fact, taht I wouldn't even waste time looking for an answer

If you're on a Unix like machine, use `grep`:

```
grep -nE \
  '^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+56666632[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+' \
  feed.txt \
  | awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

The regular expression will search for a string which contains, in order:

- At least one character which is not a white space character
- At least one white space character
- The number you're after
- At least one white space character
- At least one character which is not a white space character

using an extended regular expression.