# PHP Validate Value $_GET from url against lines of a txt file

Tags: php

i have a problem i couldn't figure out since im self-taught and still exploring the php world

so i have a text file that looks like this:

```
951753159
456787541
123156488
748651651
```

and i got an url with a variable

```
http://example.com/mypage.php?variable=951753159
```

what i want is to check if the url variable matches one of the txt file lines in order to execute a code

i already tried this

```
 $search = $_GET["variable"];
 $file = "variables.txt";
 if (preg_match('/^' . $search . '$/m', file_get_contents($file))) { 
 THE CODE THAT I WANT TO EXECUTE
 }
```

but for some reason it matches the whole content of the file

any help is highly appreciated

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a file line by line in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246597/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-php)

Comment: Maybe this could help you (possible repost) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686177/php-to-search-within-txt-file-and-echo-the-whole-line

Answer (score 1):

Try with an array from `file()`:

```
$lines = file("variables.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

if(in_array($_GET["variable"], $lines)) {
    // YES FOUND
} else {
    // NOT FOUND
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on [`file_get_contents'](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), the entire contents of the file are read as a string.  So that is why it is matching against the entire file.

The command that you want to use is [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), this reads the file into an array of each line.

Answer (score 0):

I would

Use `file` to read the file into an array.

Then `array_flip` the array so that it's values are now the keys

Which allows me to `isset($array[$key])`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
<?php
#$search = $_GET["variable"];
$search = '123156488';
$file_txt = "content.txt";
$file = file($file_txt);//convert the txt in array
foreach ($file as $key => $value) {
    if (trim($search) == trim($value)) {
        print "DO something! " . $value;
    }
}?>
```

Regards.
Nelson.