# Echo result goes in loop

Tags: php, echo

I have a html search box that uses the script below, but it seems like the echo output goes in a loop or shows all results from the .txt file that you can see I am using fopen for. I tried to add exit at the end of the echo's but then it was only able to get the first line in content.txt no matter what I searched for using the search box. I am trying to have it only show the result of what being searched for.

Here is the code I've been working on:

```
<?php
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
$f = fopen("content.txt", "r");
while (($line = fgets($f)) !== FALSE) {

    if (strstr($line, $q)) {
        echo "<li>Found $line</li>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Nothing found.</p>";
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: You can use if statement instead of while loop

Comment: @akshaykhale Hmm, I just tested that. It seems like it's only able to get the result for the first line in the txt file.

Comment: Check the answers. At least one of them would answer your question. If they do not work. add the error you are getting in the comment below each answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
<?php
    $q = $_REQUEST["q"];
    $f = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    $found = false;
    while (($line = fgets($f)) !== FALSE) {
        if (strstr($line, $q)) {
            echo "<li>Found $line</li>";
            $found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!$found){
        echo "<p>Nothing found.</p>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a built in function for pattern searching. You might find an answer here. [PHP to search within txt file and echo the whole line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686177/php-to-search-within-txt-file-and-echo-the-whole-line)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to get all the result found in the text file create a blank string and concat it in the loop if result is there echo the result else the no result found.

```
<?php
$str='';
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
$f = fopen("content.txt", "r");
while (($line = fgets($f)) !== FALSE) {

    if (strstr($line, $q)) {
        $str.="<li>Found $line</li>";
    }

}
if($str==''){
    echo "<p>Nothing found.</p>";
}else {
   echo $str;
}

?>
```