# PHP function that searches code?

Tags: php, search

I need a php function or script that can check search php code to see if certain words are used.

Example: I want to be able to search PHP files written in my own php files on my server dynamically to see if the phrase `$_SESSION` is used.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686177/php-to-search-within-txt-file-and-echo-the-whole-line

Answer (score 0):

You're better of using the `system` function in php with `grep` and check the result output. `Grep` is a very powerful tool on Linux.

```
system(grep -rl "string" /path);
```

You can also use a built in php function to search for `$_SESSION` in your files.

```
$search_text = preg_grep($pattern, file($path));
```