# Get the text just after the first ':'

Tags: php

In a txt file, there's the following:

```
Field1:Field2:Field3:Field4
Data1:Data2:Data3:Data4
```

How to get the text which is just after "Field1" which is "Field2" and without getting the ":" which is before "Field3" using PHP ?

NOTICE: "Field" won't be a constant string.

**EDIT:** I want to do something like searching for "Field2" and doing that on it's line only. So I don't want to do that for "Data" too !
Thanks.

Comment: You could checkout [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and give it a shot... Btw, what do you mean with your notice?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - Any examples?

Comment: Thee are a few examples on that link (click on the explode()-word). Just read them, give it a shot, and if you get stuck, come back and show us what you tried. This isn't a free coding service.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - Would it be like http://pastebin.com/edT7j1T9 ? ... Can I do that for "Field" only and not for "Data" ?

Comment: First explode on "\n" to get an array element for each line, then explode each line you wish with ":" separator... ?

Comment: Are you asking me if your code works? Just try it. If it does what you want, then it works. If it doesn't, try something else.

Comment: **EDIT:** I want to do something like searching for "Field2" and doing that on it's line only. So I don't want to do that for "Data" too ! Thanks.

Comment: @Random - Any examples? I'm really beginner on PHP :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: We can't code for you, you should take some lessons if you are not able to test such a simple function. The link @MagnusEriksson gave is all you need to code, with many examples and explanations of how it works...

Comment: Not sure this is even a good specification

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:*** The main goal I wanted to ask this question for is:

---

### IGNORE IF YOU WANT THE ANSWER, THE ANSWER IS BELOW:

---

I'm developing an AdminCP for my project, and if the administrator typed "*User1*" in a HTML form in the AdminCP it must return "*This user is suspended!*" if the line in the txt file was "*User1:suspended:24/01/2012*" .

While the format of users in the txt file is:

```
USERNAME:STATUS:REGISTRATION DATE
User1:suspended:24/01/2012
```

(All the texts and strings are just examples).

So in the below answer ... `$searchfor = 'Field2';` must be `$searchfor = $_POST['username'];` for example.

And I wanted to use:

```
if( $data[1]=="suspended" ) {
    echo "The user which owns ".$data[0]." is suspended!";
}
```

While $data[0] is the username (User1), and $data[1] is the status (suspended).

---

Thanks to @MagnusEriksson and [PHP to search within txt file and echo the whole line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686177/php-to-search-within-txt-file-and-echo-the-whole-line/3686246#3686246) . I just discovered the solution by myself:

```
<?php
$file = 'test.txt';
$searchfor = 'Field2';

// the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
// escape special characters in the query
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches);

$wholeLine = implode("\n", $matches[0]);
$data = explode(":", $wholeLine);
echo $data[0]; // Field1
echo $data[1]; // Field2
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, @MagnusEriksson ! :-)