# Get specific line of web page using file_get_contents

Tags: php

I have a file `test.txt` over 4 lines:

```
This
Is
A
Test
```

I have a PHP script which when I run grabs the contents of this file and displays for me:

`<?php
$file = file_get_contents('https://www.mywebsite.com/test.txt');
echo $file;
?>`

Is there any way to get a specific line from the `test.txt` file?

Comment: The `file` function already gives you an array of lines, so just get the specific line from that?

Comment: Use `file()` you get the contents of the file as an array where each item is a line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP to search within txt file and echo the whole line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686177/php-to-search-within-txt-file-and-echo-the-whole-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with new line, like:

```
$string = file_get_contents('https://www.mywebsite.com/test.txt');
$stringArr = explode("\n", $string);
echo $stringArr[2]; //get the third line
```

or use [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) which Reads entire file into an array, like:

```
$lines = file('https://www.mywebsite.com/test.txt');
echo $lines[2];
```

Comment: If the file is huge you have a lot of memory usage to read just one line.

Answer (score 2):

Use `file()` instead:

```
<?php

$lines = file("file.txt");

foreach($lines as $line){

echo $line;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use this one to read file in this line

```
        $output = fgets($file,1); // start read file in line 1
```