# reading a specific dat from a text file

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am new to php. I am trying extract a particular value from a joke file using `file_get_content( text.txt, NULL,NULL, 200, 4)` but it returns the values after the 200th character. please is there a better way to do this. like instead of specifying the position which may vary i specify a word rather

Comment: <?php
// Read 4 characters starting from the 1205th character
$section = file_get_contents('./newfile.txt', NULL,NULL,1205, 4);
var_dump($section);
?>

Comment: No, just get the whole content and after that find your word in this string

Comment: you want a particular line to be echoed?

Comment: ok will try that, thanks

Comment: Ashish i want a value to be echoed

Comment: here is the file: drops Input bandwidth utilization : 26.38% Output bandwidth utilization : 6.06%  then thekkvmmvc.                                                             so i want just the two values so that i can save in my database.

Comment: @Anarion That's a bad idea if big files are involved.

Comment: ok. I believe you should try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3686246/5588347).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this solution might be what you are looking for?

```
<?php
$mystring = 'abc';
$findme   = 'a';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

if ($pos === false) {
    echo "Not found";
} else {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
?>
```

Comment: this gives the position which is not what i want. i want the value after the position

Comment: Using substr('abcde', 0, 1); would get you the value at the given position. In this example it searches the string 'abcde' , starts at the first character and returns only 1 character. Is this perhaps what you're looking for?