# Searching array for string of original and lower case

Tags: php

I have a form that submits a string to a php script that searches through files for that string. Right now it returns exact cases (the entire line) of the user inputted string. I want to also look for an all lower case version of the users string. Is there a way to accomplish this without another foreach loop?

```
if (strpos($line, $str) !== false) {
some code here when matched

        }
```

Comment: If case is entirely irrelevant, then use `stripos()`. If not, then you need a second call to match the `strtolower()` version regardless of if it doubles the amount of calls required. You can make a convoluted regex for it, and I'm sure that someone will, but that will be more _actual_ work/CPU time than a second simple comparison.

Comment: You could use `grep -i`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686177/php-to-search-within-txt-file-and-echo-the-whole-line